# Elasticsearch Merge tokens (terms) after the tokenisation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to find a solution to combine all tokens (terms) after tokenisation.

for example - This analyser(my-analyser) produce n tokens after applying "custom_stop" filter. Is there any way to combine all tokens and generate one single token?

I have seen 'fingerprint' filter which combine all tokens but it does sorting as well, which I don't want. Please suggest solution for this.

```
 "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my-analyser": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [ "custom_stop"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "custom_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "ignore_case": true,
          "stopwords": [ "elastic", "aws", "java" ]
        }
}
```

for the input - "The concepts in elastic aws java are discussed here"
it would produce these tokens - ["concepts", "discussed", "here"],

I want to combine these three tokens and generate one token like ["concepts discussed here"]

Comment: With the custom stop filter as specified, the produced tokens would be `The concepts in are discussed here`

Answer (score 0):

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "my-analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "custom_stop",
        "concatenate_tokens"
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "custom_stop": {
      "type": "stop",
      "ignore_case": true,
      "stopwords": ["elastic", "aws", "java"]
    },
    "concatenate_tokens": {
      "type": "script",
      "script": "String.join(' ', tokens)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this would work because the keyword tokenizer would create a single token from the input (i.e. `The concepts in elastic aws java are discussed here`) and then the stop filter would not be able to remove and stop words

Comment: You are right, I've updated the example.

Comment: Curious to know where you did see a token filter called `concatenate` ?

Comment: @Val, turn out this is a custom plugin we are running. Would a combination of the "pattern_replace" token filter and the "word_delimiter" token filter be an option?

Comment: Hi @SanderToonen thanks for the updated suggestion, do you have a custom filter called "concatenate" ? if so pls post here, thanks

Comment: @Val, I tried to find the repo but can only find an old version: https://github.com/francesconero/elasticsearch-concatenate-token-filter We are running ES5 so a newer version must be available. Also, I've updated my answer with another approach you could try.

Comment: That wouldn't work as the individual tokens (as tokenized by the standard tokenizer) don't have any spaces between them anymore, they are standalone

Comment: Hmm, what version are you running. In ES7 you could try using the join processor. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/join-processor.html

Comment: The join processor is something different that transforms the document and kicks in before the indexing process. You cannot use a join processor (ingest pipeline) in a text analysis chain, it's not the same thing and they are not working at the same time

Comment: Ah, ok sorry. I'm not so familiar with that. What about building our own using script?

Comment: There's no script token filter either. The closest thing that comes to mind is to use the shingle token filter, but that's not exactly what the OP wants

Comment: @Val shingle tokeniser also produce multiple tokens.

Comment: I know that's why I said "the *closest* thing" and not "the thing"

Answer (score 0):

## Answer #1. Removing Stop Words by Regular Expressions

You can use the straightforward method and add all the stop words in a regular expression pattern. The source text isn't splitted into tokens (the `keyword` tokenizer)

```
GET /_analyze
{
    "tokenizer": "keyword",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase",
        {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "\\b(are|aws|elastic|in|java|the)\\b",
            "replacement": ""
        },
        {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "(\\s){2,}",
            "replacement": "$1"
        },
        "trim"
    ],
    "text": "The concepts in elastic aws java are discussed here"
}
```

The second `pattern_replace` filter remove multiple space symbols

The disadvantage of this method is the inability to use the stop word filter

Answer (score 0):

## Answer #2. Concatenating Terms in a Runtime Field

You can use a runtime field to concatenate terms. Set `fielddata` = true on the field with text

Mapping

```
PUT /concatenated_terms
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "standard_custom_stop_list_filter_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "custom_stop_list_filter"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "custom_stop_list_filter": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "ignore_case": true,
                    "stopwords": [
                        "elastic",
                        "aws",
                        "java",
                        "_english_"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "runtime": {
            "text_concatenated_terms": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "script": {
                    "source": """
                        List terms = doc[params.field_name];
                        String concatenatedTerms = String.join(params.term_delimiter, terms);
                        emit(concatenatedTerms);
                    """,
                    "params": {
                        "term_delimiter": " ",
                        "field_name": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard_custom_stop_list_filter_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Document

```
PUT /concatenated_terms/_doc/1
{
    "text" : "The concepts in elastic aws java are discussed here"
}
```

Search query

```
GET /concatenated_terms/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "fields": [
        "*"
    ],
    "_source": false
}
```

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "concatenated_terms",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "fields" : {
                    "text" : [
                        "The concepts in elastic aws java are discussed here"
                    ],
                    "text_concatenated_terms" : [
                        "concepts discussed here"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```